# White border around app icon on Android 10

Tags: android, android-layout

I keep getting this white border on my app icon "App Name" - does anyone know how I can get my icon to look like e.g. the "Settings" or "Messages" app icon that doesn't have a white border?

[image]

I have tried using the following filenames but these all seem to add a white border:

- ic_launcher
- ic_launcher_round
- ic_launcher_foreground

Here's my app icon:

[image]

Environment:

- Sonim XP8
- Android 10
- Android security update: March 1, 2022
- Build number: 8A.0.5-08-10.0.0-31.11.00

Comment: It has little to do with specific filenames. You need to follow [the adaptive icons guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive). If you think that you are doing so, show us your adaptive icon setup as part of a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to File -> New -> Image Asset. Then choose Launcher Icons as the Asset Type.
2. Choose a High-res image for the Image file: Next -> Finish to generate icons.
3. Finally update `android:icon` name field inside the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, if required.